# Ejecutar esta funcion

Tags: c#, net, vs, core

lo que quiero es poder ejecutar esta [función](https://long2know.com/2016/05/parsing-excel-to-a-list-of-objects/).

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this ExcelWorksheet worksheet, Dictionary<string, string> map = null) where T : new()
{
....
}
```

Estoy que lo intento con esta sentencia de la tercera linea:

```
var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
ExcelWorksheet workSheet = currentSheet.First();
var x = ImportarExcel.ToList(workSheet);
```

Pero siempre me dice : "Los argumentos de tipo para el metodo 'ImportarExcel.ToList(ExcelWorkSheet, Dictionary<string, string>)' no se puede inferir a partir del uso. Pruebe a especificar los argumentos de tipo explícitamente"

Por favor alguna ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Es porque `ToList` es un método genérico que recibe un argumento de tipo `T` que no estás especificando.

Comment: Debes llamar a `ToList<ElTipoEnLaLista>(workSheet)`

Comment: Gracias Hertor, parece que eso era lo que faltaba, voy a probar con la siguiente sentencia: 
var x = ImportarExcel.ToList<ExcelMapa>(workSheet);